# Verify Firebase Instance Id on Server

Tags: firebase, firebase-admin

I have an android app integrated with Firebase.
I have followed the instructions mentioned on the firebase console for the integration.

My app needs to send the Instance Id to the backend in its API requests.

I am using the following code to obtain the Instance ID

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.e("QUICKFOX", "getInstanceId failed", task.getException());
                    return;
                }

                // Get new Instance ID token
                String token = task.getResult().getToken();
                Log.e("QUICKFOX",">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
                Log.e("QUICKFOX",token);
                Log.e("QUICKFOX",">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");

            }
        });
```

I am using the service to validate the Instance Id
https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#get_information_about_app_instances

I am not sure about the following:

1. Is the Authorization: key= passed as query param or Header.
   From the example it seems as if it is passed as query param. but the
   documentation says it is a Header.
2. Either way (as Header or as query param), I am getting 401 Unauthorized as response (Also response type seems to be text/HTML)
3. What to send as API KEY. I used webAPIKey still I get 401. I used the api_key in google-services.json still the same 401 error.

Can any one help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. I don't really understand the difference but this worked for me.
The [API](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#get_information_about_app_instances) is expecting a server key which can be found here:

1. Go to firebase Console.
2. Click on Project Settings
3. Click on Service Accounts
4. Click on the other service accounts
5. This will open GCP Console.
6. Click on the Hamburger menu on the top left corner
7. Click on APIs & Services
8. Click on the Credentials
9. locate the server key as shown in the below screenshot and copy the
   key. This is the API key which can be used to validate the instance
   Id tokens

[image]

[image]

[image]